# how to find identical columns in different tables

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have two tables each with multiple columns.

```
+------+-------+--+
| Col1 | Col2  |  |
+------+-------+--+
|    1 |  1231 |  |
|    2 |   123 |  |table 1
|    3 | 14124 |  |
+------+-------+--+


+------+-------+--+
| Col3 | Col4  |  |table 2
+------+-------+--+
|    1 |  1231 |  |
|    2 |   323 |  |
|    3 | 14324 |  |
+------+-------+--+
```

I want to check is if `col1` and `col3` are identical. That is: all the values match, to be determined using sql?

I dont want to use `except` and also I don't want to take difference of the two columns and check if its zero.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you share those queries you've tried, and explain why you don't want to (or "can't"?) use them? What is your goal?

Comment: I used 'Select (table1.col1-table2.col3) as difference from table1,table2'

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?  Can't you join the tables together and compare?

```
select
...
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.col1 = table2.col3
```

Comment: i do not want the common values , inner join will give me the join of two table on the key, i want to check if the columns are identical or not

Comment: @Shiven: I don't understand, that query will give you the rows where the columns match.  You said: "I want to check is if col1 and col3 are identical".

Answer (score 0):

You can `outer join` them and filter on null results

```
select table_1.col1, table_2.col3
from table_1 full outer join table_2 on table_1.col1, table_2.col3
where table_1.col1 is null
   or table_2.col3 is null
```

This will give you all records where one of the values of either column does not exist in the other table.